# How to defend and attack single database on server?

Tags: webserver

Lets say I would have my own web server with MySQL database hosted together with new website. What are the techniques that I can protect it and what are called the attack that can query my db ? Is that even possible ? What are the threats and against what should I got protected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Only allow connection from localhost if you dont require external connection to your db
2. Use strong password
3. Don't create application vulnerable to SQL injection